# How can I upload tags and branches of svn repo from local to bitbucket

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I have already transferred trunk of SVN repositories to bitbucket.
Now I want to upload tags and branches of that repository.

The problem is : I don't want all the tags and branches from SVN to be uploaded.
I just want recent two.

Going forward I have checkout all the required tags and branches in local.

now, forgetting about SVN. Can someone help me directly uploading that tags and branches which are there in Local system to my bitbucket repository?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow able to manage this!

1.Create a branch in Bitbucket(Initially it will contain master branch content), say branchname be Branch1.

2.Now To make the changes in Branch1, we first need to connect it from local, create one empty folder say folder1.

3. Now we need to make this file git compaitable. For that follow the below steps :
   a) go to that directory in gitbash.
   b) git init //to initialize it to a git folder.
   c) git remote add remotebranch http://wholeclone URL of the branch/repo. //this will create one remote area for us to make the change.
       NOTE: remotebranch is an arbitrary name which we are going to use for referring remote area.

4) The above step will link the local folder to the bitbucket.

5) Now to make the changes, lets fetch the branches from the bitbucket, for that we do :
    git fetch remotebranch

6) now you will see some branch listed over as an output.

7) now lets go to that branch in which we need to do the changes by following command :
    git checkout Branch1

8) Now if you see in the local folder, you'll find the content of bitbucket branch1 to be reflected here.

9) Now as we want to put our content instead of the already present data! we will delete all the files in folder1 except .git folder.

10)Now place the content in local folder which you want to move to bitbucket.

11) once placed, let's go back to the git bash and run following commands.
    git status //will show us the changes happened
    git add . //to add everything to the staging area
    git commit -m 'initial commit' //to commit the changes in staging area.
    git push // to finally push the changes to bitbucket.

and you are done.